# Log mqtt client data on a separate file - Spring Boot

Tags: java, logging, authentication

I'm developing a spring boot application and I have a question about the log in which I'm doing with mqtt:

The log of the data that arrives from mqtt client, can be done from the logger of Spring, but at a separated file, or is it required to create a specific class that will log these data, outside of the data of application operation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log incoming data from MQTT client, you use the logger statement with level set to info/debug depending on the requirements.  It need not be a separate class/file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but maybe I explained the problem badly, the point is that for me it is necessary that the data from the broker MQTT (as well as those sent by the client MQTT) are logged on a separate file compared to the log of operation of the application. Can it be done?

Comment: Can you please check the log configuration available with MQTT broker.  I think it should be available out of box, by changing the config we should be able to get the logs of data coming to MQTT broker.